# How to position form elements in rows, while having label and element be adjacent to each other?

Tags: html, css

I want to create CSS that

- sets width of Label to 100px
- positions select/input elements to the right of the label
- positions {label, element} sections in rows

So far my CSS is failing...   I don't know how to do it.  In short I want this:

```
Label:   [  ... ]
Label2:  [ ...  ]
Label3:  [...   ]
```

How?

```css
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div><label>
    <span>Label:</span>
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</label>
  <label>
    <span>Label2:</span>
    <input name="motor" value="44" type="number">
</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the HTML structure that you have, you would want to set the `span` to display as `inline-block` and the `label` to `block` to set it on a new line.

Setting `span` to `inline-block` allows it to be inline but still maintain its box styles (width, for example).

```css
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {display:block}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <span>Label:</span>
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Label2:</span>
    <input name="motor" value="44" type="number">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put each `label` in seperate `div` element that resolve your issue. Try the given link or below code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcs3uygf/2/)

HTML Code-

```
<div>
    <label>
        <span>Label:</span>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <span>Label2:</span>
        <input name="motor" value="44" type="number">
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS Code-

```
span {
    width: 100px;
}
```